# Copy a 3 dim array in itself

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I have  to create a Sudoku Game in C and for the "Undo" Function I want to copy the first 3 dim. array into the next one.

The Problem is that my program breaks up while `i=j=0`, so it does not even start to copy the array.

Here is what I have:

```
void copydim(int sudoku[z][9][9])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            sudoku[dim + 1][i][j] = sudoku[dim][i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

`z` is defined as 10.

`i` and `j` are lines and columns of the Sudoku.

Here is the invocation: its a simple switch instruction where the sudoku should be copied when the user press the 1

```
case 49:
    if (sudoku[dim][yvek][xvek] >= 0)
    {
        copydim(sudoku[z][9][9]); /*my debugger says that the sudoku array has the right values here, but in the next step when my programm switches into the copydim function there are no more values and an error occurs, although the pointer to the sudoku is the same as in this function :(*/
        sudoku[dim][yvek][xvek] = 1;
        editanzeige(sudoku, x, y);
    }
    break;
```

Declaration of my array is in my main function.

Comment: And what is `dim`? What is its value when the code "breaks"?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to initialize `dim`, yes? This code should work as long as `dim` has a useful value. By the way, "the code breaks" is not a very useful error report. Segfault?

Comment: sorry I forgot, the value of dim is declared with 0. The value is also 0 when it stops

Comment: There isn't enough context to identify the problem.  Please show the invocation of `copydim` and the declaration of the array that's passed to it.

Comment: put dim++ after the j loop..

Comment: ok so here is the invocation: its a simple switch instruction where the sudoku should be copied when the user press the 1 
`case 49: 
if (sudoku[dim][yvek][xvek] >= 0) 
{ 
copydim(sudoku[z][9][9]); 
/*my debugger says that the sudoku array has the right values here, but in the next step when my programm switches into the copydim function there are no more values and an error occurs, although the pointer to the sudoku is the same as in this function :(*/ 

sudoku[dim][yvek][xvek] = 1; 
editanzeige(sudoku, x, y); 
} break;` 

@TomKarzes declaration of my array is in my main function

Comment: please place additions//edits to the question in the question itself and not a comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line in the comment:

```
copydim(sudoku[z][9][9]);
```

is passing a single field in a single instance of the sudoku array.

Infact, A field that outside the bounds of the single instance of the sudoku[][9][9] array.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

What is really needed is to pass an address.

```
copydim( &sudoku );
```

suggest:

```
#define MAX_ROWS (9)
#define MAX_COLS (9)
#define MAX_GAMEBOARDS (10)

struct gameboard
{
    int rows[ MAX_ROWS ];
    int cols[ MAX_COLS ];
};

// declare the array of gameboards with name `sudoku`
struct gameboard sudoku[ MAX_GAMEBOARDS];

int dim =0;
```

where `copydim()` is prototyped as:

```
void copydim( struct gameboard * );
```

where the sub function is invoked by:

```
int main( void )
{
    ...
    copydim(sudoku);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the original `copydim` code you've posted at all.

However, it will crash if the array passed in is not allocated (null), and *might* crash if `dim` or `dim + 1` falls outside the bounds of the array.

The mistake is in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

There is the mistake I made ... 
The invocation of copydim was wrong

```
copydim(sudoku[z][9][9]);
```

it has to bei `copydim(sudoku);`

Thanks a lot for the try :)
Despite of that I learned a lot of how I have to write my questions in Future :D